# IIS starts application twice after app pool restart

Tags: .net, windows, iisreset

I'm facing an issue with my application.
It's being hosted on IIS, hosting model out of process, application framework .net 6.
Once in a while, after application restart, ISS starts two processes.

Those are the logs from Event Viewer

10:41:57 Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' started process '14564' successfully and process '14564' is listening on port '40701'.

10:41:57 Sent shutdown HTTP message to process with Id '14564' and received http status '202'.

10:41:57 Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'XXX' shut down process with Id '14564' listening on port '40701'

10:42:04 Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' started process '12184' successfully and process '12184' is listening on port '47678'.

The problem is, the process id 14564 is still running afterwards, even though logs are claiming it has been shut down.

Do any of you have any clue what might be causing that?

Checked all application pool settings - all seems to be fine.
Tried to reproduce the bug with 100% repeatability - no luck.